# Couchbase 5.5: Why does putting '\\' in meta.id make search faster?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Couchbase 5.5
N1Ql

I have 150k documents in a sandbox couchbase database where the document name is in the following format:

```
alpha_model::XXXXXXX::version
```

When I run this command:

```
SELECT META().id FROM Q1036628 WHERE META().id LIKE "alpha_model::100004993::%" LIMIT 10;
```

result count: 5. Elapsed time is `1.13s`

However, when I add a '\' before the '_' the performance is greatly increased to

```
SELECT META().id FROM Q1036628 WHERE META().id LIKE "alpha\\_model::100004993::%" LIMIT 10;
```

result count: 5. Elapsed time is `8.16ms`

Why is the second way over 100 times faster? Are underscores bad? Are there any other characters I should escape to improve performance

Comment: Are these queries returning the same documents? Also, what is the typical load on your system? (reads/writes/document size) And how much RAM are in your nodes? Why did you put \\ into the string in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

_ is wildcard to match any character at that place. If you want to search exactly you need to escape it. Checkout LIKE at  https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/comparisonops.html

You might not have any other character at that place due to that your results are same. If you have any other character at _ the results will be different.

As IndexScans can't be done on wildcards, IndexScan done on prefix string until first wild card. That is reason without escape character IndexScan producing more results and taking time. By escaping _, the wildcard character starts at %.

Do EXPLAIN and checkout the Spans for correctness and optimized.

Checkout Page 152, How predicate is transformed into IndexScan spans  https://blog.couchbase.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/N1QL-A-Practical-Guide-2nd-Edition.pdf
Checkout Page 341 Optimize query using request profiling.